# How to show\Hide button according to scrolling in ionic4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

[image]I want to use scrollToTop in my ionic project . In my code scrollToTop working but i am want to show button when scroll the content in ionic . How to show sticky button in ionic please help me... 
In images my button show at end want to show at middle and show when i am scrolling..

tab1.page.html

```
        <ion-content cache-view="false" (ionScrollStart)="logScrollStart()" (ionScroll)="logScrolling($event)"
          (ionScrollEnd)="logScrollEnd()" [scrollEvents]="true">
        <button class="scroll"  (click)="ScrollToTop()">
              <ion-icon name="arrow-dropup-circle"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            </ion-content>
```

tab1.page.ts

```
ScrollToTop(){
    this.content.scrollToTop(1500);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "when I'm scrolling", you can detect if your heart icon is visible in your scroll-able card with something like:

[How to Check if element is visible after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling/21627295#21627295)